# Can you set up Swagger to let you download query results in CSV format?

Tags: json, csv, swagger

I'd like to do queries on Swagger UI and be able to click a button to download a CSV of the results. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you mean? Also, when you say Swagger, which of the [Swagger tools](http://swagger.io/tools/) you mean?

Comment: @Helen I'm talking about Swagger UI.

Comment: Your question still needs much more details to be answerable. What is "CSV of the results"? Does your API returns a response of type `text/csv` and you want to save the response to a file instead of (or in addition to) displaying the response in Swagger UI? Or what? Please be more specific.